# ReferenceError: $ is not defined in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in JavaScript and I didn't know how I am getting this error ? I upload my site but I am not able to open my site in any mobile. I think this must be responsive error

[image: this is my error which I am facing]

That's my code where I having error:

```
$('#bookNow').live('click', function(){ 
  $('#PU_type').val() == '') {
    myRedAlert('Submit Booking', 'Please select pickup location.');
    return false;
  }
```

I don't know what is the problem and also I am using the jQuery library

Comment: All indications are that you are not including your jQuery library before the Javascript. Care to post your HTML or a link to your failing site.

Comment: You have to include jQuery, and stop using `live` it's deprecated and removed.

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate of a 'thousand' other questions on SO regarding the same thing.

Comment: @adeneo, it's only deprecated if the OP using an up-to-date version of jQuery.

Comment: try using jQuery instead of $.

Comment: its also possible that you just missed to have $ in scope of the inner body of your function - see my answered standard implementation of jQuery and be aware of the datails...

Comment: Tip: Read the [jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). It tells you exactly how to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Some Kind of a Standard implemention of jQuery

*adopted from http://html5boilerplate.com/ as well*

HTML:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="path/to/your/local/fallbackversion/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="path/to/your/application.js"></script>
</body>
```

And the content of your "path/to/your/application.js" is wrapped into:

```
(function( window, document, $ ) {
    // do your function definitions and whatever doesn't need the document to be ready event
    $(function() { // document ready
        // do your stuff on the DOM
    });
})( window, window.document, window.jQuery )
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is just to include your jquery library before your code.!

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    // Your code!!!!
</script>
```